# Lock on object's field value

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

My microservice is receiving messages from a rabbitMQ and storing it on CouchDB,
I am creating multiple consumers thread to process them, and my code throws ConflictUpdateException because of the race condition which is occurring i.e.

> Thread X, Y read couch db value for the same Object at the same time; Thread X updates the record in Couch before Thread Y, but Thread Y
>   is updating the record on basis of the hash value(_rev) before X 
>   modified record.

Object's Unique Identifier is composite: name+age+id,

> How can execute a critical section only for threads with same
>   (name+age+id) ?

Possible ways I don't want to implement:

1. lock on String value(name + age + id). 
   [as not a good practice]
2. HashMap of String and CustomObjects for locking. 
   [as i don't have a memory bound on count of unique Object]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep track of _rev:

- Retrieve the document, take note of the _rev property that CouchDB sends along
- Edit the fields you need
- Send the updated document back, using the _rev property
- If the _rev matches the currently stored number, be done!
- If there's a conflict (when _rev doesn't match), retrieve the newest document version and edit again what you need to edit. Go to step 3

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [concurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) structure, holding locked primary keys. 
Their representation is up to you, that discouraged string would work just as good as instance of some specialized class implementing *hashcode+equals*.
Your consumer will iterate over input queue attempting to lock a record by calling atomic *putIfAbsent()*. If this succeeds, it will do its *storeToDatabase()* call, and then *remove()* entry from that map. Otherwise moves to next entry in queue.

In this way you'll need only few(count of consumers) entries in this map of locked keys, 
not having huge memory consumption, and paralleism level would be very high. It will not preserve the incoming order though.